# Hide bootstrap buttons in navigation on threshold

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, typo3, responsive

I'm currently working on making a static design responsive using bootstrap integrated in TYPO3. I started out by creating the navigation bar and am running into first problems.

[**Current layout (desktop view)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TPwG.png)

[**Current layout (resized window, smaller)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYJz3.png)
Notice how the social media buttons are jumping out of the navigation bar? I would love to hide them completely at this point.

When resized even more to a smaller width, same goes for the search field - jumps out of navigation bar at certain window width. I would love to keep this until the navigation bar switches to collapsed, so on for example iPad (768x1024) you could still search.

**My html template right now**

I'll adapt the template so it doesn't contain TYPO3 variables, but the generated output you would use without TYPO3:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Port</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prrrrrrrrriint</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <form class="navbar-form" action="suchergebnisse">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Suche" name="q" id="srch-term">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="cmd" id="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a class="link" id="link-youtube" href="#" title="#" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li><a class="link" id="link-googleplus" href="#" title="#" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li><a class="link" id="link-twitter" href="#" title="#" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li><a class="link" id="link-facebook" href="#" title="#" target="_blank"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

I've tried playing with the collapsed classes, but being out of twitter-bootstrap business for a while hasn't been good for me. I'd appreciate any hints you might have!

Answer (score 0):

For faster mobile-friendly development, use these utility classes for showing and hiding content by device via media query. Also included are utility classes for toggling content when printed.

For more info [Bootstrap Doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

add below bootstrap class for hide html element based on your requirement.

```
hidden-xs for Phones (<768px) resolution 
hidden-sm for Tablets (≥768px) && Desktops (<992px) resolution
hidden-md for Desktops (≥992px) && Desktops (<1200px)resolution
hidden-lg for Desktops (≥1200px) resolution
```

Comment: While that's the answer to how one can hide elements in certain viewports - thank you - it still doesn't resolve the problem of the social media buttons and search box jumping out of the navigation bar at certain thresholds!